# Can I have layout-definition and layout-render in the same jsp file in stripes?

Tags: java, stripes

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="stripes" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld"%>    

<stripes:layout-definition>some definition</stripes:layout-definition>
<stripes:layout-render name="someName" />
```

And then by loading the content of that jsp I will get the content of the layout rendered. The way I do it now is to have two separate files, one with the definition and the other one containing only the render-code. This seems wasteful and basically duplicates the number of required jsps.

I am limited to use Stripes 1.5.3 as there are migration issues with moving to 1.5.7

Answer (score 0):

[Content outside of the  is blithely ignored](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Layout+Reuse), but you can have nested layouts:

```
<stripes:layout-definition>some definition
  <stripes:layout-render name="someName" />
</stripes:layout-definition>
```